# Пишу бота для телеграмма, используя библиотеку telebot. Нужна функция для удаления веб-приложения с клавиатуры

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Не могу разобраться в документации. Я чайник в программировании, не кусайте) Нужно убрать кнопку "открыть приложение") Подскажите молодому, как это сделать. Библиотека telebot.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ:

Найдите в `Telegram` BotFather(папу ботов)

[image: papaBots]

Введите команду `/mybots`, перейдите в настройки вашего бота

[image: settingBots]

Далее вам нужно перейти по следующей команде(кнопке)

[image: menuButton]

И последнее это

[image: disable]

Comment: Через BotFather вопрос решается частично. Если есть необходимость в определенный момент скрыть эту кнопку для пользователя. Как это сделать через код?

Comment: @Юрий, Мне как раз показалось, что в начале вы хотели именно это, потом показалось, что вам нужно убрать полностью. Все же, если вам нужно появление подобного меню через определенную логику, почитайте [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/666278/)